# Tons of "invalid command \N" when restoring a dump

Tags: linux, postgresql, upgrade

I'm following these instructions to upgrade postgres from 9.1 to 9.3:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html

When I restore (Step 8), I get a ton of messages like this:
`psql:/mnt/dumps/pre-upgrade.dump:61028: invalid command \N`

Does anyone know the problem or can point me to a better upgrade instructions for Linux?

Comment: Are you using `pg_upgrade`? Looks like it from the filename, but it'd be good to confirm. If you are, show the entire log from `pg_upgrade` please. Pastebin it if it's too big for here. Edit question, comment here when done.

Comment: No step 8 exactly "/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -d postgres -f outputfile"

Comment: That message comes up whenever `COPY tablename ...` has a problem.  Once the COPY command errors out, the remaining rows of the COPY command are interpreted as their own commands and produce spurious errors like this one.  You'll need to look at the beginning of that list to see the actual error.

Comment: Using `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f outputfile` will help, btw, as it'll stop after the first error so you can see what it was. Did you make sure you're using the new version's `pg_dump` and `psql` like the instructions say? `psql -V`, `pg_dump -V`.

Comment: Ah no I did not use a newer version of pg_dump.  If it works with an older version should I be OK or should I kill the process now and redump/re-restore?

Comment: "9th November 2023: PostgreSQL 16.1, 15.5, 14.10, 13.13, 12.17, and 11.22 Released!" (source: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-93-released-1481/), and the  [community bot](https://serverfault.com/posts/587635/revisions) still bumps this question....

Answer (score 0):

I had a dump from `pg_dump`.
My error output was:

```
psql:export.sql:1: error: invalid command \n
psql:export.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ÿþ"
```

I tried escaping and replacing to fix `\n`, but still had the `ÿþ` error.
To fix the `ÿþ` error I tried encoding to `UTF-8`.

At some point i started all over, made a new export and only converted the export to `UTF-8`. No error was outputted anymore, so **that fixed also the** `error: invalid command \n`.